# Converting a string into an attribute in Python

Tags: python, reflection

Is it possible to do something like this in Python?

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        someValue = 42

        str = 'a'
        # self.a = someValue
        str = 'xyz'
        # self.xyz = someValue
```

Essentially what I want to achieve is by reading the value of `str` (say the value of `str` resolves to `'myValue'`), the code adds an additional attribute (`self.myValue`) into the class.

Comment: `setattr(self, str, someValue)`?

Comment: It's probably better that you don't use `str` as the name of a variable, since it's the name of a built-in type.